# Unable to use __init__.py

Tags: python

I must be missing something simple here.

I have a directory structure:

```
maths/
    __init__.py
    test.py
    ...

    foo/
       __init__.py
       ...

    bar/
       __init__.py
       ...
```

In multiple files (but not all) I am using the path of the module - on Ubuntu for example - that path is `/home/nebffa/Desktop/maths` for some tasks. However, I have to compute the path of the `maths` package in all of those files - so I thought maybe it will be easier to just have it available via `__init__.py`. At least that's what I thought I could do based on reading up on `__init__.py` - maybe I'm wrong?

Anyway, attempts to make things available by putting them in the base `__init__.py` have failed to work so I think I might be misunderstanding this Python concept.

Comment: What does "test.py is just itertools" mean?

Comment: @Adam The text in `test.py` is literally just `itertools`, which is enough to throw this error.

Comment: I think you misunderstood `__init__.py`.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: @laike9m I thought so too, but then it says "execute initialization code for the package" - which is what I am using it for?

Comment: @nebffa Yes,the initialization code will be executed when the package is imported for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `python test.py` then `__init__.py` is not involved at all.

Comment: How do I run it so that `__init__.py` is involved?

Comment: You would have to run it on the `maths` folder itself, as a module.

Comment: You have to import the entire `maths` module, or import `maths.test`

Comment: @SethMMorton like `python -m maths.test`?

Comment: @Adam `import maths` works but does not have `itertools` in the namespace. `import maths.test` errors with the same `NameError` as in the question.

Comment: You should edit your question with what you're trying to accomplish. Clearly this isn't your entire project, and any solutions have to work within the larger context.

Comment: That's one way to do it.

Comment: Yeah I just ended up ignoring __init__.py in the end, and made a separate module maths_path.py to hold the directory of the package.

Answer (score 1):

`maths` and `maths.test` are two separate modules, each with their own distinct namespace. You will need to explicitly import `itertools` in `maths.test` if you want it available there.

Also, `python -m maths.test`.

Comment: I thought I could put things in `__init__.py` and they would automatically be imported upon trying to run/import test.py?

Comment: No. Each module has its own distinct namespace.

Comment: @nebffa Why don't you just put `import itertools` in `test.py`?

Comment: @Adam I actually want to put the overall package's path in __init__.py - I am calling it in a number of places in my package and it is getting annoying. `itertools` is just a simple example I was trying to test.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `python -m maths.test` returns the exact same error.

Comment: @nebffa: Of course it does. It doesn't magically make what you want work.

Comment: @nebffa A python package is a **module**, like any other. The difference is that, instead of having the module file called `module_name.py` it is called `package_name/__init__.py`. Doing `import package` searches for a directory called `package` that contains a `__init__.py` file and builds a **module** out of `__init__.py`. There is *no* special behaviour involved. Since in python there are no such things as "globals", you *always* have to import the things you need in a module, so you have to do when writing a package.